# Recursion function reverse BYTE

Tags: recursion

```
FUNCTION Y(s : STRING) RETURNS STRING
 DECLARE x : INTEGER
 x = LENGTH(s)
 IF x = 1
  THEN
   RETURN s
 ELSE
  RETURN Y(RIGHT(s, x - 1)) + LEFT(s, 1)
  // RIGHT above returns rightmost x - 1 characters of string s
  // LEFT above returns leftmost character of string s
 ENDIF
ENDFUNCTION
```

How to dry run this recursion when s="BYTE"
For call(4) i get YTE and B
is it correct ??

Comment: your output is `YTEB`? A reversed string would be `ETYB`

Comment: But how to dry run it and it's a pseudo code not on computer.

Comment: if it's not a computer, then YOU are the computer and you write out on paper exactly what's going one at each line of code until you get a result. We're not a code translation or execution service.